# How to obtain consistent behavior across different hosts for docker volumes permissions?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Kindly asking for help to make sense of what I'm doing over here. I'm trying to mount as read-only a folder and have the `apache` user being able to read it. I'm having different behaviors on different servers

I start a container with a Dockerfile as such, note the second volume being mounted as read-only

```
sudo docker build -f Dockerfile -t myimage .
sudo docker run -tid --name="mycontainer" -v /my_ro_folder:/var/mystuff:ro myimage )
```

My Dockerfile is as follows (summarized):

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker

RUN yum -y install ....;
RUN mkdir /var/mystuff

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

Now, I see two different behaviors on two linux servers running the same distro and I don't understand why. I tried removing containers and purge the system thinking it was some cache but to no avail.

SERVER1:

```
ls -la /my_ro_folder
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 netadmin users  128 Jun 25 12:12 .
$ id -g netadmin ; id -u netadmin
100
1032
```

SERVER2:

```
ls -la /my_ro_folder
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 netadmin users  128 Jun 25 12:12 .
$ id -g netadmin ; id -u netadmin
100
1026
```

Now, on SERVER1, I get permissions just fine in the container:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 1032 users 128 Jun 25 10:12 mystuff
```

While on SERVER2 I don't, they remain as such and consequently, the apache user can't read:

```
d--------- 1 1026 users 128 Jun 25 10:12 mystuff
```

On the containers there is no user 1026 or 1032 in neither of them. Both have the group `users:x:100:` though.

What is going on? why is there such a behavior .. and how can I get a consistent behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Anything that depends on bind-mounts from the host will intrinsically have host-specific behavior.  On native-Linux systems, the host's user IDs will be visible inside the container, but on MacOS they'll get remapped to something else.  The actual content will vary between hosts, and if you try to deploy the container to another system, you'll have to bring the content along with it.

You can avoid this by including the content in your image, and not using a bind-mount at all.

```sh
FROM centos:7
RUN yum -y install ....;
COPY mystuff /var/mystuff  # creates the directory
CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
# no need for a VOLUME declaration of any sort
```

```sh
sudo docker run -d --name="mycontainer" -p 80:80 myimage # no -v option
```

If you're used to having a live *development* environment, this isn't it.  But if you're looking for a *deployment* setup, this means you can run the image as-is without copying other content over or worrying about filesystem permissions.  If you give each image build a unique tag then you can very easily roll back to yesterday's build, and you can run a copy of the proposed container in a pre-production environment without worrying about whether you've correctly copied the files over.

Comment: Thank you for your reply -- the data I'm mapping is updated by the host constantly and read (thus ro) by the container. Am I correct to understand the copy solution can't work in my case?